# Add array to multiarray using only variables to refer to arraynames

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

In order to use arrays in functions, I'd like to learn how to refer to them via names defined in variables. This is why very simple thing is done here in a rather complicated way...

```
Remove-Variable array*
Remove-Variable first*
Remove-Variable second*
$arrayname='name'

$arrayfirst='firstarray'
Set-Variable -Name $($arrayfirst + $arrayname) -Value $(cat textfile.txt)
$(Get-Variable -Name $($arrayfirst + $arrayname) -ValueOnly) -is [array]
```

**True**

```
$(Get-Variable -Name $($arrayfirst + $arrayname) -ValueOnly)
```

First row

Second row

Third row

```
$arraysecond='secondarray'
Invoke-Expression "`$$($arraysecond + $arrayname)= @()"
$(Get-Variable -Name $($arraysecond + $arrayname) -ValueOnly) -is [array]
```

**True**

```
Invoke-Expression "$($arraysecond + $arrayname)+= ,$(Get-Variable -Name $($arrayfirst + $arrayname) -ValueOnly)"


$null -eq $(Get-Variable -Name $($arraysecond + $arrayname) -ValueOnly)
```

**False**

**but**

```
 $null -eq $($(gv $($arraysecond + $arrayname) -ValueOnly)[0])
```

**True**

which means the array containing the rows wasn't added properly.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the 2nd Invoke-Expression, which makes it work the way you want:

```
Invoke-Expression "`$$($arraysecond + $arrayname) += `$(Get-Variable -Name $($arrayfirst + $arrayname) -ValueOnly)"
```